# IE Browser - Powershell script to add site to trusted sites list, disable protected mode & make all zones security level low

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, registry

For our website to run we need to:

1. add site to trusted sites list [Solved]
2. disable IE protected mode [Solved]
3. bring down security level for all zones. [facing Issue]

I am automating this site. As a prerequisite i have to take care of security features.

***I have create below code. But i am not able to set security level to zero. I can't find 1A10 in zones.***

[image: My Registry]

**I am adding solved issues code as well. Hoping it might help someone in need**

**Helpful sites** -

https://x86x64.wordpress.com/2014/05/20/powershell-ie-zones-protected-mode-state/
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/182569/internet-explorer-security-zones-registry-entries-for-advanced-users
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/04/02/update-or-add-registry-key-value-with-powershell/

```
#1. Add site to trusted sites

#Setting IExplorer settings
Write-Verbose "Now configuring IE"

#Navigate to the domains folder in the registry
set-location "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
set-location ZoneMap\Domains

#Create a new folder with the website name
new-item testsite.site.com/ -Force #website part without https
set-location testsite.site.com/
new-itemproperty . -Name https -Value 2 -Type DWORD -Force

Write-Host "Site added Successfully"
Start-Sleep -s 2

# 2. Disable IE protected mode

# Disabling protected mode and making level 0

#Zone 0 – My Computer
#Zone 1 – Local Intranet Zone
#Zone 2 – Trusted sites Zone
#Zone 3 – Internet Zone
#Zone 4 – Restricted Sites Zone

#“2500” is the value name representing “Protected Mode” tick. 3 means Disabled, 0 – Enabled

#Disable protected mode for all zones
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1" -Name 2500 -Value "3"
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2" -Name 2500 -Value "3"
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3" -Name 2500 -Value "3"
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\4" -Name 2500 -Value "3"

Write-Host "IE protection mode turned Off successfully"
Start-Sleep -s 2

# 3. Bring down security level for all zones

#Set Level 0 for low 
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1" -Name 1A10 -Value "0"
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2" -Name 1A10 -Value "0"
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3" -Name 1A10 -Value "0"
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\4" -Name 1A10 -Value "0"

Stop-Process -name explorer
```

Thanks in Advance Guys!!

Comment: I wonder if group policy admin templates would have all the necessary settings?

Comment: @vonPryz - Thanks for your reply and time. let me check.

Answer (score 2):

just remove "0" and replace with 0 it worked for me.

```
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2" -Name 1A10 -Value 0
```