# Change User Authentication for IE security settings within trusted/Intranet domains using Powershell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

The desired goal is to create a powershell script to configure custom level settings within internet options for either zone: local intranet or trusted sites. So far I have been successful with the individual settings but User Authentication is my roadblock. I can't get it to select **Automatic logon with current user name and password**.

[IE Security Settings - User Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67fC9.png)

I've reference these following articles/solutions for my code but its not clicking for me:

- [Article 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720030/ie-browser-powershell-script-to-add-site-to-trusted-sites-list-disable-protec)
- [Article 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/browsers/ie-security-zones-registry-entries)
- [Article 3](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a747fb36-5ecd-4a95-8b4c-3f4ea6f7f3b7/powershell-how-to-set-automatic-logon-with-current-username-and-password-in-internet-explorer)

The code below is tailored to Trusted Sites:

```
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2" -Name 1406 -Value "0"
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2" -Name 2102 -Value "0"
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2" -Name 1607 -Value "0"
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2" -Name 1400 -Value "0"
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2" -Name 2103 -Value "0"
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2" -Name 2105 -Value "0"

Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2' -Name "1A00" | Set-ItemProperty -Name "1A00" -Value "0"
```

The first 6 lines work fine...its the last one that is giving me a headache. I've tried the following code but none seem to select **Automatic logon with current user name and password**. No errors as well:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1' -Name "1A00" | Set-ItemProperty -Name "1A00" -Value "0x00000000"
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1' -Name "0x00000000" | Set-ItemProperty -Name "0x00000000" -Value "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I did a simple test on it, and I found that the code works correctly.
This is the result of the test：
[image]

Do you keep the security setting panel open when you execute the code? I thought it might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have the setting panel closed when executing the code. The result of your test stumps me because running the code as admin still doesn't yield what you demonstrated.

Comment: You mentioned that there is no error message after executing the code. As shown in the image above, when the code is executed, can you see that the registry value has been modified?